# Which FSx System is attache to which EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-fsx

I have multiple AWS FSx File Systems. Is there a way to find which FSx systems is attached with which EC2 instance ?

Comment: Are these Windows instances ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no straightforward way to see this in the AWS console, but in the case of **Windows** instances, one way of doing this is by:

1. Log into one of the instances that is connected to the **Active Directory**
2. Use the **Shared Folders** tool( *fsmgmt.msc* ).You need a user in the domain admin group, and then you
3. Connect to the DNS name of the FSx file system, for example: `fs-9498985948485.ad-domain.com` 
   You can then see the connected sessions (User, Computer)

[image]